# Required Attribute on a Radio Button Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried multiple suggested fixes for this problem including using the required attribute on only one input and using required="required." At this point, I'm not sure what to do. Any advice on a solution would be really helpful. Thank you for your time! Here's my code:

```
function questionGenerator(score, multipleChoiceQues, completedQuestions) {
  return `
    <form role="form" class="question-form">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>${multipleChoiceQues.question}</legend>
          <label class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="ans" value="${multipleChoiceQues.answerOne}" required>
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerOne}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
          <label class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="ans" value="${multipleChoiceQues.answerTwo}" required>
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerTwo}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
          <label class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="ans" value="${multipleChoiceQues.answerThree}" required>
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerThree}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
          <label class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="ans" value="${multipleChoiceQues.answerFour}" required>
            <span>${multipleChoiceQues.answerFour}</span>
          </label>
          <br>
          <button class="answer-submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>


    <section class="question-and-score">
      <span class="currentQuestion">Question: ${multipleChoiceQues.num}/10</span>
      <span class="currentScore">Score: ${score}/${completedQuestions}</span>
    </section>`;
}
```

Here's the link to the entire project, if you're interested:

https://repl.it/@joshing_you/Fortnite-Battle-Royale-Quiz-App

Comment: What is the expected vs the actual behaviour?

Comment: The expected behavior should not allow the user to move on to the next question without selecting one of the four inputs. It should also display text stating that the user must select one of the options. The way it is now, you can go through the whole app without selecting a single input.

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to select a radio button by default use :

```
checked="checked"
```

```html
<form>
  Select Gender:

  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male</label>

  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't want a preselected input, I just want the inputs to be required so you can't just skip through all of the questions without selecting an input.

Answer (score 1):

In your `submitButton()` function, you can check if no answer has been selected, show an alert and return:

```
const answer = $("input:checked").siblings("span");
if(answer.length===0){
    alert("please select an answer");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Let me give that a try.